# Ask direction of/from someone in street?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do we "ask direction from someone" or "ask direction of someone"?

Example:

> As I didn't know the address, I asked direction **from/of** a total
>   stranger in the street.

Comment: You would probably write "I asked *for* direction *from*," or more idiomatically, "I asked *for direction**s** from*."

Comment: I do not normally vote to migrate to ELL, but this belongs over there, at least if some research is provided.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime I didn't get why it should be "directions" in plural?

Comment: @Sasan That's just the word for it. I guess it's assumed that finding a location is a multi-step process.

Comment: @Sasan Because when asking for directions, you typically move in more than one direction in order to get to where you want to go. *"take a left at the light, then turn right at the next stop, ..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer:

> As I didn't know the address, I asked a total stranger in the street **for** directions.

Generally, you do not ask information **from/of** a person - you ask a person **for** information.

However, if what you need is not information but an object to use for a short time or a favor, then you may either "ask it **of** them" or "ask them **for/to do** it".

> Person A: I need somebody to wash the dishes while I'm out.
>
> Person B: You should ask it of the servant.

or

> I needed to see his passport, so I asked it of him.

Answer (score 3):

It would "ask directions from him", because directions are coming from the person giving directions. "Directions" is plural because it usually involves a series of actions to follow the instruction on how to arrive to the destination.

Comment: I didn't get why it should be "directions" in plural?

Comment: This answer is unclear, unsupported,  and delivered in a non-idiomatic form.

Comment: What *direction* am I driving? North. Then can you give me **directions** to the art museum? Sure, that should be two rights, but because of the one-way streets, it's more turns...

Answer (score 0):

> As I didn't know the address, I asked direction from/of a total stranger in the street.

I would say the most idiomatic form of this statement would be:

> Since I didn't know the address, there was a complete stranger in the street and I (just) asked him/her/them for directions.

Or, to rearrange..

> I asked a total stranger in the street for directions because I didn't know the address.

And then, to use the verbiage you are bringing into question (from vs of):

> As I didn't know the address, I asked directions *from* a total stranger in the street.

At first thought, I can't think of any scenarios where *of* would sound natural within this context.